# Want to purge 3 months old data from database

Tags: sql-server

I want to purge 3 months old data from database, but problem is I don't have date column in that table.

Is it possible by any means? Please help me out

Comment: You are going to need either a date column, or some other column which can logically serve as a proxy for the date.  Maybe add some sample data to your question.

Comment: ...and maybe show some effort. If you don't have any sort of date column, then how do you expect to calculate age of the data? Is there an Id column you can map to creation date?

Comment: No there is no column in table that serve as proxy for date

Comment: How do you determine the data is `3 months old` ?

Comment: By "three months old data", do you mean with respect to the insertion date into the table or to some attribute that has not to do with insertion date?

Comment: Yes i mean to say with respect to the insertion date into the table

Comment: hmm. well technically "date" field is your easiest ticket in order to achieve purging of data but unfortunately you do not have. If you have any "TimeStamp" on your table. You could use that

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any information about the insertion date, the short answer is no. 
One option would be to **add a date field** to the table, which you give a default value of **GETDATE()**. Then everytime when you insert a new value it will get the insertion timestamp. But this will of course not give you the correct insertion date for the old records.